# TASKKILL specific Python script

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a working TASKKILL command that kills python.exe using *Process Name*

I'd like to narrow the scope of the command to kill a specific process (myScript.py) but can't use *ProcessID* as it changes with every run.

Is there a way I can add detail from the *Command Line* which knows the python script's name?

Current Command:

```
Taskkill /IM python.exe /F >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo PYTHON.exe NOT FOUND) else (echo PYTHON.exe KILLED)
```

Comment: If python.exe is attached to a console, and you're ok with closing the console and all processes attached to it, then set the console window title to something that uniquely identifies this script and use `taskkill.exe /fi "windowtitle eq <title>"`.

Comment: Note that there's no need for `/f` when using the title *without* the `/im` option, since taskkill will close the console window based on the title rather than terminate the process directly. This also gives the script a chance to exit gracefully using a console control handler.

Comment: You can code this using either PyWin32 or ctypes, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Not attached to a console unfortunately, just a background process.

Comment: How is python.exe getting run? If it's a service or task, there are better ways to stop it.

Comment: It's called from a batch command issued by Informatica.  It works silently in the background but needs killed at a process level ahead of a server reboot. I cant just reboot the server as I also need to un-schedule the workflow and that happens after the python script is stopped.

Comment: python.exe is probably attached to a console, but possibly with a hidden window. In the script, check whether `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()` is non-zero.

Comment: Alas I know not how to run that.  Instead I added /FI "USERNAME eq MyUser" which at least means I'll only kill scripts called by the Informatica user.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to kill it based on your Python script's memory usage.  In my case, the Python script is running a GUI, so the size gives it away.

```
taskkill /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" /fi "MEMUSAGE gt 130000"
```

This reads as, forcefully kill the task (`taskkill /f`) identified by (`/fi`) the Python executable (`IMAGENAME eq python.exe`) which is using more than 130,000KB (`MEMUSAGE gt 130000`)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> See `taskkill /?` for builtin help.

---

N.B. You might find this SO post helpful: [Find Windows PID of a python script with Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677623/find-windows-pid-of-a-python-script-with-windows-command-prompt?rq=1).  Unfortunately, for me, It Doesn't Work™ but maybe you will have better luck.