# Find Windows PID of a python script with Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt, taskkill

I am running two different python scripts running on a windows machine simultaneously and would like to kill one but not the other from the command prompt. Using taskkill with the name "python.exe" does not allow me to choose to kill just one of these scripts.

Is there a way in windows to kill just one of these tasks, determined by the script from which it originated?

For example: if I run python_process1.py and python_process2.py and would like to kill the .exe associated with just python_process2.py and leave python_process1.py alone.

UPDATE: the solution below does not kill the process, and the issue still lies in identifying the PID of a process by python script name. If this is impossible, is there a way to selectively kill python scripts on windows that I am unaware of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Get-WmiObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) and PowerShell you can examine the command line arguments for each process, then pass the selected Process ID to taskkill.

This example shows how to kill a process executing the script `test.py`:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> taskkill.exe /F /PID $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'python.exe'" | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -like '*.\test.py'} | Select -ExpandProperty ProcessId)
```

Modify `*.\test.py` to match how you are actually calling each script, and it should work for you

Comment: From PowerShell, it would be better to keep a reference to the python.exe process in order to terminate it explicitly, rather than searching the command lines and using taskkill.exe.

Comment: Hi - finally got around to implementing this and the command is throwing in error with regard to the syntax. "Value expected for PID." First thought was that the script being searched for wasn't running, but it is. Any thoughts?